# DIV that fills the browser window even with zoom

Tags: html, browser, static, zooming, positioning

I would like my background DIV to fill the entire browser window at all times.  I have a DIV on top of the background that is moving the way I want it to, I have the positioning set by percentages.  When I zoom out, both DIVs move together, creating exposure of the background color.  Here is my site:

http://search.officesupplycentral.org/details.html

Here is an example of how I would like my DIVs to function:

http://fab.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jim

Comment: did you try putting the "background-image" property for body?
V

Comment: put in body.. 
background:url('image.jpg') fixed;background-size:100%;

Answer (score 0):

[fab.com](http://fab.com) uses a special approach which is easy to see if you just check the code of the site.

It sets the background to the HTML tag `<html style="background-image: url(//s3.amazonaws.com/static.fab.com/relaunch/fab-daily-design-for-everyone-8.jpg);">` and sets the following values to it in the CSS file:

```
html{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It then sets the background to `<body>` to transparent in the CSS:

```
body{
  background: transparent;
}
```

My educated guess without researching this further is that since the image is set as a background on the `<html>` tag and with the background-size set to cover it isn't handled when the page is zoomed in or out.